# Prevent code from re-executing before it's complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

I have the following scenario:

```
$('button').on('click',function(){

    // Run AJAX commonds (May take some time);

});
```

So If the user clicks the button several times, he could be executing a `ajax` request a lot.

The logical way to solve this is to use

```
var finished = true;
$('button').on('click',function(){
    if(finished == true){
        finished = false;
        ....
        finished = true;
    }
```

But adding global variables to every function seems bizarre? How can I fix this? I looked into `.off()` but this complete remove the event. `one()` just execute it once. I wan't it to execute multiple times. Maybe writing a simple plugin to take care of this functionality. Its repetitive.

Answer (score 0):

You can add data or add a class to the element to indicate that it's still processing. Then remove that data/class name if the operation is done.

```
$('button').on('click',function(){

  var self = $(this);
  var processing = self.data('processing');

  if(!processing){ //if not processing

    self.data('processing',true); //flag as processing

    //do stuff
    $.ajax({...}).done(function(responseData){

      //when done, unflag
      self.data('processing',false);
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: This is bad practice as the user can still click the button twice before the .css()/attr() excutes. No.

Comment: @Jessica That's why you check **before** you do something. Besides, it's just similar to your global flags approach, but does not use global flags.

Comment: Not really - I wouldn't use this approach but since JS is single-threaded, no JS can execute before the Async Ajax call is initiated. See [this page](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/) for more information

Comment: @JosephtheDreamer I see it makes sence now, but yet still repetitive code that could be combined into a custom function?

Answer (score 0):

An option could be to disable the button when a request is active.

```
$('button').click(function() {
    //or in the ajax beforeSend function
    $(this).prop('disabled', true);
    $.ajax({
        ...
        //or directly after the user clicked the button
        beforeSend: function() {
            $('button').prop('disabled', true);
        },
        ...
        //complete or success callback
        complete: function() {
            $('button').prop('disabled', false);
        }
    });
});
```

But with this method you should define which button is disabled and not clickable anymore. Unless you want all buttons to be disabled. 
I created a <kbd>[**working example (jsfiddle)**](http://jsfiddle.net/SirDerpington/2ggbA/1/)</kbd> for your to test this. (with an 1s delay after AJAX complete, so you notice the disabled button)

Using a [Timeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) could be another option, so the AJAX call won't fire if a user presses a button repeatedly. If the AJAX call takes longer than the timeout your problem still exists.

```
var timer;    
$('button').on('click', function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout( function() {
        // Run AJAX commonds (May take some time);
    }, 500);

});
```

Comment: I'd go for disabling, but not timers. If I click the buttons 1 second apart, they will still run.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to learn `.on()` an `.off()` methods: http://jsbin.com/oguwux/1/edit

HTML:

```
<button id="btn">AJAX REQUEST</button>
```

jQuery:

```
function ajaxCall(){

  $(this).off('click');
  $(this).text('Processing...'); // test only

  setTimeout(function(){  // (example.) do your AJAX call instead
    // ON SUCCESS :
    $('#btn').text('AJAX REQUEST');
    $('#btn').on('click', ajaxCall);
  },2000);

}

$('#btn').on('click', ajaxCall);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this: (untested):

```
var InProgress = Array();
function OneAtATime($jQueryAjax) {
    var Id = arguments.callee.toString().match(/function\s+([^\s\(]+)/)
    InProgress.push(Id)

    for(var i=0; i<32; i++)
        result += Math.floor(Math.random()*16).toString(16).toUpperCase();
        return result
    }

    CallBacks = {
            success: function(x,y,z){$jQueryAjax.success(x,y,z);Remove(Id);,
            error: function(x,y,z){$jQueryAjax.error(x,y,z);Remove(Id);,
            fail: function(x,y,z){$jQueryAjax.fail(x,y,z);Remove(Id);
        }
}

function Remove(Id) {
    InProgress.splice(InProgress.indexOf(Id),1);
}
```

Sample Usage:

```
OneAtATime({
    /*  Usual jQuery.ajax properties  */
    url: '/Callback';
    success: function(data, status, xhhr) {
        alert('success');
    }

});
```

As mentioned in comments on another answer, there's no chance of a race condition since Javascript is single threaded.